# ESP32 xTaskGetTickCount doesn't return correct values

Tags: esp32, freertos

why does this simple code not working, and if xTaskGetTickCount doesn't work, what should be alternative?

```
static void PrintTextEvery8sec(void *pvParameters)
{


                TickType_t time_start = xTaskGetTickCount();

                while(1){

                    if( ( (xTaskGetTickCount() - time_start)/portTICK_PERIOD_MS) > 8000){
                        ESP_LOGI(TAG, "8 seconds has passed...!");
                        time_start = xTaskGetTickCount();
                    }

                    vTaskDelay(100 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
                }
 }
```

Comment: Did you solve it? What happens if you add a ESP_LOGI(TAG, "running"); to the loop to ensure it is "running"?

Comment: Yes.. I will put the answer now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it doing the following:

```
static void PrintTextEvery8sec(void *pvParameters)
{


                TickType_t time_start = xTaskGetTickCount();

                while(1){

                    /*  pdTICKS give correct calculation */
                    /*  \/                               */
                    if( pdTICKS_TO_MS(xTaskGetTickCount() - time_start))** > 8000){
                        ESP_LOGI(TAG, "8 seconds has passed...!");
                        time_start = xTaskGetTickCount();
                    }

                    vTaskDelay(100 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
                }
 }
```